# Get Pixels From Rotated Bitmap Android

Tags: java, android, graphics, bitmap

I am working on a game in Android and I have `Bitmap` objects being drawn. They are rotated using the `Matrix` class. The problem I am having is being able to access the pixels of the rotated `Bitmap`. When I access them after rotation the pixels are still representing the unrotated version. Does anyone have any ideas? Maybe I can rotate the pixel array based on an arbitrary number of degrees? I have seen solutions that create a new bitmaps on the fly based on the newly rotated images, but I can't do this because of performance issues. Thanks!

Here is how I draw the bitmap currently (The bitmap is drawn using the matrix as its position)...

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPlayer, positionMatrix, null);
```

Here is how I create the positionMatrix variable...

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(degrees, bitmapCenterX, bitmapCenterY);
positionMatrix.set(m);
```

Here is how I access the pixels currently (This accesses the pixel array I created below)...

```
getPixel(x, y);
```

Here is how I build the pixel array that I have tried to modify...

```
// Build pixel 2d array
pixelData = new int[bitmapPlayer.getWidth()][bitmapPlayer.getHeight()];

for(int x=0; x<bitmapPlayer.getWidth(); x++) {
    for(int y=0; y<bitmapPlayer.getHeight(); y++) {
        pixelData[x][y] = bitmapPlayer.getPixel(x, y);
    }
}
```

Here is how I have tried to manipulate the array...

```
public void rotatePixels(int degrees) {
    int[][] newPixelData = new int[bitmapPlayer.getWidth()][bitmapPlayer.getHeight()];

    double cos = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees));
    double sin = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees));

    for(int x=0; x<bitmapPlayer.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<bitmapPlayer.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(pixelData[x][y] != 0) {
                int currentX = x + getTopLeftX();
                int currentY = y + getTopLeftY();

                int nextX = (int)((currentX * cos) - (currentY * sin));
                int nextY = (int)((currentX * sin) + (currentY * cos));

                if(nextX >= 0 && nextX < bitmapPlayer.getWidth() && nextY >= 0 && nextY < bitmapPlayer.getHeight()) {
                      newPixelData[nextX][nextY] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this.pixelData = newPixelData;
}
```

Comment: @Michael I updated my post with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(45);
Bitmap newBm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapPlayer, 0, 0, bitmapPlayer.width(), bitmapPlayer.height(), mat, true);
```

and then accessing the pixels of the new Bitmap?

I think right now you just draw a rotated bitmap on the canvas, you're not actually rotating the bitmap

EDIT:

The way you do it in your orinigal post won't work because you start at (0,0) and work your way down the left column... Depending on the rotation degree you'd have to start at a different place and then go down a different column. i.e. a small ctrclkwise rotation and you start at the top right index.

```
Bitmap bm = someImage;
int startx, starty;
int degree = rotateDegree % 360; // counterclockwise
if (degree >= 0 && degree < 90) {
    startx = bm.getWidth();
    starty = 0;
} else if (degree >= 90 && degree < 180) {
    startx = bm.getWidth();
    starty = bm.getWidth();
} else if (degree >= 180 && degree < 270) {
    startx = 0();
    starty = bm.getWidth();
} else {
    startx = 0;
    starty = 0;
}
```

And then try traversing the image that way, starting at (startx, starty)
and adding or subtracting the correct angle (you can use some boolean to keep track
of whether you're adding or subtracting from x or y respectively). Let me know if this works,
and if it doesn't can you be a little more specific about where you think the problem might be?

Comment: I have done this and it is way to slow for my needs. I had high hopes that this would be an easy solution when I had tried it too. It does exactly what I need, but at a major loss in performance unfortunately...

Comment: Edited -- let me know if that helps at all

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thanks for putting some thought into it, I appreciate it. I'll prob throw this method into C and access it through JNI to help with performance a bit too. I'll get back to you when I get a chance to try it.

Comment: No problem -- you might skip pixels though with rounding and such, or count others twice. How accurate does it need to be? What do you need to do with the pixel data?

Comment: Yea I know it wont be perfect and I think after a while it would be completely messed up but I'll need to try it. I was hoping to make it pretty accurate. My game has some pointy images that collide with bigger images and I need it to be pretty precise.

Comment: This didn't seem to do it unfortunately... What I ended up doing was to convert the local bitmap pixel coordinate to a world coordinate. This allows for more accuracy and I don't have to keep manipulating the same array which would eventually start to lose/merge pixel locations. It seems to work pretty well for my needs.